# Get column names of Nested field BigQuery

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I want to get the schema of a view, just column name and type. But I have a nested column of type RECORD. how do I get the column names for the nested column using the schema? Here's the python code I am using :-

```
dataset = client.dataset("mydataset",project = "myproject")
table = dataset.table("myviewname")
table_data = client.get_table(table)

for schema in table_data.schema:
    if schema.field_type == "RECORD" :
        print("{} : {} ".format(schema.name,schema.field_type))
        # Help here
    else:
        print("{} : {} ".format(schema.name,schema.field_type))
```

I also tried getting the data using :-

```
Select * from `myproject.mydataset.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMN_FIELD_PATHS` WHERE table_name="myviewname" and column_name ="NestedColumn"
```

Comment: Is this useful? https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-tables#column_field_paths_view

Comment: No that just gives me data_type as ARRAY<STRUCT<key STRING, value STRING>> . I don't see the key names. I posted the query in my initial question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the cloud shell in the BQ interface and parse the JSON.

`bq show --schema --format=prettyjson dataset.table`

Comment: That doesn't give the column name or data, it gives the same output as the query.

Comment: Please check again.  This command gives a nested JSON representation of your schema, with column names and column types, including the nested/repeated records and their "sub-columns".